# Problem with depth first search output in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the following code:

```
s(a, b).
s(b, c).
goal(c).

solve( N, [N] ) :-
    goal( N).

solve( N, [N1 | Sol] ) :-
    s( N, Nl),
    solve( Nl, Sol).
```

When I enter the query:

```
solve(a, P).
```

It gives me :

```
P = [_,_,c] ? 

yes
```

But I want the complete path e.g.

```
P = [a,b,c] ?
```

Comment: You mixed up `Nl` and `N1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your predicate you use two variables that look similar (graphically):

```
solve( N, [N] ) :-
    goal( N).

solve( N, [N1 | Sol] ) :-
    s( N, Nl),
    solve( Nl, Sol).
```

Here `Nl` (with a lowercase L) looks similar to `N1` (with a one 1). In fact the Prolog interpreter recognizes that `N1` is only used once, and raises a warning:

```
?- ['file.pl'].
Warning: /tmp/file.pl:8:
        Singleton variables: [N1] 
true.
```

The `N1` variable has nothing to do with the `Nl` variable defined in the body, and thus remains ununified.

But that being said, if you really want to output here, you should use `N` in the "path" construction, not `N1`, since otherwise for `solve(a, L)`, `L` will start with `b`, not `a`, and will mention the last node (here `c`) twice, so:

```
solve( N, [N] ) :-
    goal( N).

solve(N, [N | Sol]) :-
    s(N, Nl),
    solve(Nl, Sol).
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped.
What is your secrete for learning prolog? our instructor isn't teaching us much.

Comment: @sosscs: I think [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/) can be quite helpful.